# Remove string before read as table in R

Tags: r, apache, logging

I try to analyze apache server logs with R.

To read the data I use `fread` or `read.table`. After more than 450 tsd. lines both functions were stopping early because of an unusual string "unknown" in the beginning of the line.

I edited the logs manually by removing this string and both functions were working fine.

Is there an option to remove this first string in R? My problem is, that I cannot even load this data to manipulate it.

Normal line:

`url.com 123.456.7.89 - - [01/Nov/2022:00:01:01 +0100] "GET ...`

And the strange one:

`unknown url.com 123.456.7.89 - - [01/Nov/2022:00:01:01 +0100] "GET ...`

Thanks!

Comment: Try something with `readLines`.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that `fread` or `read.table` are the right tool for reading that kind of data; how are you calling them when the full load works without error? Regardless, perhaps `readLines(pipe("grep -v -E '^unknown' /path/to/file.txt))` might work.

Comment: both fread and read.table work well with regular "clean" data, in your case few lines cotain unkown characters and therfore break, try readChar(), or readLines() or scan().

Comment: thanks all, `readlines` with a pipe to `sub` worked fine!